# create layout using CSS for following design

Tags: html, ios, swift, css

We are trying to achieve the following layout based on dynamic **html string**.

Here we are facing when it is second page content layout not going up & we can not add images in first page.

The sample code tried in native code as below:

```
 func setData(){

        let dic = arrayData[currentIndex]
        url = dic["ImageLink"] as! String
        self.url = self.url + "_MEDVPF.gif"
        content = dic["ArticleXML"] as! String

        let height = String(describing:webViewObj.frame.size.height - 100) + "px"
        let width = String(describing: self.view.frame.size.width / 3 - 20) + "px"

//        let style = "<div style=color:#0000FF>" + String(describing: dic["HeadLine"]!) + "<br /><br />" +  String(describing: dic["Abstract"]!) + "</div>"

        self.headlineLabel.text = dic["HeadLine"] as? String
        self.abstractLabel.text =  dic["Abstract"] as? String
        var styleCSS = "font-family: TAUN_Elango_Abirami; font-size: 18px; column-width: %@; column-gap: 10px; height:%@;>"
        styleCSS = String(format:styleCSS,width,height)

        let bodyStyle = "<div style= \"%@\""  + content + "</div>"
        let bodyStyleConten = String(format:bodyStyle,styleCSS)



        let htmlString =   String(format:bodyStyleConten)
        let finalDiv = "<div>" + htmlString + "</div>"
        webViewObj.loadHTMLString(finalDiv, baseURL: nil)

    }
```

[image]

How can I do this Html5 with CSS, that should be horizontal scrolling?

We have tried with **core text** in iOs,but we have facing slowness issue.So we decided to go with **uiwebview**?

We did this with **CoreText** framework, only issue with this layout is slowness when its content very very large.We checked many way, but no lucks? We are not able to fix slowness, help would be appreciated, i will share sample also if anyone interested to contribute.

Comment: Wow, this is rare! ;)

Comment: @nashcheez Thanks, any other suggestion?

Comment: This kind of news application

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of separate issues that make up your problem and layout is just one of them.

If you're going to tackle it yourself in HTML/CSS, I'd recommend starting with `overflow-x: scroll;` on the container which holds your content, and looking at this information about CSS columns https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts, but with a caveat that columns aren't uniformly supported across browsers, so it might be wise to avoid them or implement them differently.